# Connect to MonetDB via JDBC without specifying database name on Linux

Tags: java, linux, jdbc, monetdb

Our Java application works as the following:
- it connects to the server without specifying any database name,
- checks if the given database exists and creates a new one if not.
On Windows, the application works fine but on Linux it cannot connect to the server. The error message: "monetdbd: please specify a database".
We would like to run the same Java application on Linux and Windows. Is there any method to check and create database from Java on both operating system?

Answer (score 1):

We have figured it out at last. A client can connect to an existing database only. On Windows the installer creates a demo database. If other database is not specified, the client connects to it automatically.
On Linux the installer does not create any database, so it should be created
manually.